# Pass UserId in Querystring or Identity Cookie in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, cookies

I am building a .NET Core 3.1 Razor Page Application. I am using a cookie-based authentication provider without ASP.NET Core Identity to handle authentication/ authorisation.

I have several pages within the application (update profile, password etc.) where the UserId for the logged-in user is passed in the Querystring, e.g.`/User/User/1` or `/User/UpdatePassword/1`

If a logged-in User attempts to change the UserId in the Querystring to access (or update) another Users details, I have a check in the PageModel that determines if the UserId in the  querystring matches that of the `NameIdentifier Claim` within the `Identity Cookie`.

```
public void OnGet(int UserID)
{
  if(UserID != Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value))
  {
    //Potential malicious user
  }
}
```

This logic works, however, I'd appreciate feedback on whether this is deemed secure, or if users on this site have faced a similar situation with an alternative approach?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this user have any business related to permissions?

Comment: @Chaodeng Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Can you provide an example?